# Load jquery module after an angularjs view has loaded?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

How do you load a javascript file after an angularjs view has loaded?

I want to apply a third party script on a view, but it only works when I reload the full page, not when the view is called.

So I'm thinking that the code referenced on the html view  is not processing in the right order.

Comment: Use a directive to wire up the jQuery stuff to the element(s). If needed you can wrap the function inside `link` in a `$timeout()`. This will ensure Angular has processed before your jQuery stuff.

Answer (score 0):

you may try to use deferred (lazy) load modules like this https://oclazyload.readme.io/
i use it for load heavy tiny mce (js lib + angulat directive)

for example loading from ctrl

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($ocLazyLoad) {
  $ocLazyLoad.load('app/js/testModule.js');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To force code to run after Angular is finished loading, you can add the following code:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
       //load jquery module here
});
```

You can replace "document" with whichever element must be in place.